# Asp.Net Core Api Authorization

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, authentication

I have an Asp.Net Core / ReactJs aopplication.  I'm using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer` to authenticate the API.  However, I'm getting an error, which I believe is down to bad configuration.

If I run this locally, with the following config, everything works, and the app redirects to the log-in screen as expected:

```
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "MyApp": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA",        
      }
    },
    "Key": {
      "Type": "File",
      "FilePath": "Assets/selfsignedcert.pfx",
      "Password": "password"
    }
  },
```

However, if I change the config to the following:

```
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "MyApp": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA",        
        "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:5211/authentication/login-callback"
        "LogoutUri": "https://localhost:5211/authentication/logout-callback"        
      }
    },
    "Key": {
      "Type": "File",
      "FilePath": "Assets/selfsignedcert.pfx",
      "Password": "password"
    }
  },
```

It errors (redirecting to the following):

```
https://localhost:5211/home/error?errorId=1234...
```

Looking at the auth request, from the client, they are exactly the same; however the second returns an error, while the first successfully redirects.

Is there something wrong with my config?  Alternatively, how can I debug this issue?

Comment: Could you please share the error too

Comment: All I’m getting is the redirect to an error page.

Comment: Have you checked the browser's developer tools (or Fiddler) to see exactly how the redirect occurs?

Comment: Yes.  Where the config is ‘bad’ it redirects from the auth request

Answer (score 0):

Both of your Uris in the non-working configuration point to logout. Is this really what you're trying to do?

In the first configuration, you're not defining any Uris, so they will have the following default values:

The redirect_uri defaults to /authentication/login-callback.
The post_logout_redirect_uri defaults to /authentication/logout-callback.

As documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#application-profiles)

Try changing the second configuration to match the default values to see if that helps.

Comment: Apologies: I'd obviously made some kind of error while tidying up the copy, the RedirectUri does, in fact, point to login-callback (I've updated it in the question).  You're correct that the RedirectUri points to /authentication/login-callback by default; and if I change it to the default value explicitly then it works.  However, I can't deploy it with the default value - and specifying the full url (as described in the example you linked to) redirects to an error page

Answer (score 0):

The client configuration of `redirect_uri` and `post_logout_redirect_uri` must be identical to the IDP:

```
redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:5211/authentication/login-callback',
post_logout_redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:5211/authentication/logout-callback',
```

Or

```
redirect_uri: $'{IDPhost_config}/authentication/login-callback',
post_logout_redirect_uri: $'{IDPhost_config}/authentication/logout-callback',
```

Comment: Is that not what I currently have (sorry if I’m missing something obvious)?

Comment: Your question is missing the client's configuration, isn't it?

Comment: The documentation would seem to imply that the client config was translated from the client profile: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Where do you think I'm missing this config?